# Does placement of 'subscribe()' within code matter?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a question pertaining to placement of code that uses RxJS - more specifically code that involves subscribe.

If I have the following example placed inside of a function

```
  this.genericService.getXYZ().pipe(
    takeWhile(() => this.componentActive)
  ).subscribe((x) => {
    ...
  });
```

does every time that this function gets called mean that I am creating a new subscription?

If I were to take the same code snippet above and assign it to a variable and place it at the top of the file (outside of a function), this to me makes it so that only one subscription is created because it only gets called once each time

I am just curious if I should be approaching my code differently with respect to subscriptions within a function?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear? What do you want to achieve or why do you want to approach your code differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technical answer is that yes, every time you call that function a new subscription will be created.

Take this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fdksqf

```js
this.subject.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
).subscribe(() => {
  this.log.push('value received');
});
```

If I call this function 3 times, I will push 3 values to the log property whenever a value is received from `subject`.

How you best manage this is a matter of opinion, and I'm not going to stray into that discussion here.